# How do I invalidate cache of an embedded view?

Tags: views, 8, caching

I have a node type "Article" that contains a repeating [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) field. One of the paragraph types let's the user embed a view using a entity reference field. When rendering an Article node containing a views reference I embed the selected view in `hook_preprocess_paragraph` like this:

```
$view_id = $paragraph->field_view->target_id;
$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView($view_id);
$view->setDisplay('embed_1');
$vars['content'] = $view->preview();
```

This is working fine except when I enable caching. For example one of my views lists nodes of the type "Event". When I add a new Event it does not show up in the listing until I clean the cache. I could force clean the cache when inserting / updating / deleting an "Event" but I would much rather use Drupal 8's cache tag system and only invalidate the cached content that contains event lists. The problem is I cannot get it to work.

So far I have tried adding cache tags to the node, the view, and the paragraph  in `hook_preprocess_paragraph` and `hook_preprocess_node` like this:

```
$vars['paragraph']->addCacheTags(['node_list']);
...
$view->storage->addCacheTags(['node_list']);
...
$vars['node']->addCacheTags(['node_list']);
```

According to [this page](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/cache/tags) `node_list` can be used for node listings to invalidate the cache whenever a node is updated. But it has no effect. Maybe the preprocess hooks are to late to add cache tags?

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

After some more testing I found that if I edit an event, the changes can be seen in the listing and if I remove an event it disappears from the listing. The problem only occurs when adding new events.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use `buildRenderable()`, that should ensure that the necessary cacheability metadata is added automatically.

```
$vars['content'] = $view->buildRenderable();
```

Hint: You might be interested in my [Views Custom Cache Tag](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_custom_cache_tag) project. The node_list cache tag is invalidated every time any type of node is saved, even though your view only changes when an event changes. Using that module and a bit of custom code as shown on the project page, you have fewer cache invalidations and better performance.

Comment: How do I render the results of ```$view-buildRenderable()``` in my twig file? When using ```$view->preview()``` I could just do ```{{ content }}``` in my twig template but it does not work.

Comment: It returns a render array, that should wok fine. Are you using an embed display? If so, I recently found a core bug there, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2711973. as a workaround, just set #embed => TRUE yourself in $variables['content'].

Comment: Yep, I'm using embed displays, and setting #embed => true manually works great! Thanks Berdir! Will definitely check out your module as well.

Answer (score 3):

Add the cache tag to the render array, not the object:

```
$vars['#cache']['tags'][] = 'node_list';
```

In preprocess you are working with render arrays, not objects. Look at this page of the documentation: https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/render/arrays/cacheability

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! For my issue, Berdirs answer fixed my problem without having to add cache tags manually.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I agree, that is a great answer from @Berdir. I upvoted it too.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue using the module [Views Custom Cache Tag](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_custom_cache_tag):

In the view editor, under Advanced, click on Cache, then select "Custom tag based". To have the view rerendered each time a node is changed, enter 'node_list' in the custom tag settings.