# How do I programmatically render a view with contextual filters?

Tags: views, 8

How do I programmatically render a view with contextual filters in Drupal 8?

In Drupal 7, I generally use the following code.

```
$view = views_get_view('test_view'); //test_view is the view machine name
$view->set_display("block"); //block is the view display name
$view->set_arguments($tid); //$tid is the argument to pass
$view->pre_execute();
$view->execute();
$content = $view->render();
```

Is there any alternative way to achieve this in Drupal 8?

Comment: What exactly do you want to pass as an argument? maybe you can achieve what you want through the View's UI.

Comment: Yes i know i can achieve that using view UI but that is not possible in my case, i want to achieve it by some code only.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Basing on the code used by [`views_get_view_result()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.module/function/views_get_view_result/8.2.x), I would use the following code, as code equivalent to the one you show in the question.

```
  $args = [$tid];
  $view = Views::getView('test_view');
  if (is_object($view)) {
    $view->setArguments($args);
    $view->setDisplay('block');
    $view->preExecute();
    $view->execute();
    $content = $view->buildRenderable('block', $args);
  }
```

Comment: That's not rendering, that's just getting the results. Not the same :) The preferred way to do this is to use $view->buildRenderable($display, $arguments), see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198920/how-do-i-invalidate-cache-of-an-embedded-view/198946#198946

Comment: Yes, I was wondering the same, about result versus rendering. `:D`

Comment: $content does not contain html (its an array) ... how do I get to an actual html output from this ? could it be that views internals have changed ?

Comment: to answer my own question: one need to do drupal_render($content) to get actual rendered string

Comment: @GiorgosK With Drupal 8, you never use `drupal_render()`. It's enough you return a renderable array, which even a controller class can do.

Comment: @kiamlaluno well for my use which is to modify/override the output from a views REST  EXPORT (json output) passing the $content to the field formatter was just outputing "Array" on the json output ... so after I passed the `drupal_render($content)` it actually gave me the rendered output on the json output ... am I missing something ? is there any place to understand what you just explained ?

Comment: @GiorgosK: if you use Drupal itself for display, you don't render these days, you leave it everything in a render array up to the last point and let the system do the rest. But if you need to lift the result from Drupal (maybe to put into a newsletter or similar), then you render, yes. But start not to use `drupal_render()`, it will be deprecated.

Comment: just reminder for multiple arguments id selected allow multiple  you can use $arguments = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$args = [implode(',' ,$arguments)];

Comment: One more thing that should be done, is add $view->postExecute(); add the end to close off the view. Otherwise the view being rendered will still be "active" and views_get_current_view returns that view, which can mess with things being rendered later.

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way to render a view in Drupal 8 is using the render element provided by core: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Element%21View.php/class/View/8.9.x

```
  $view = [
    '#type' => 'view',
    '#name' => 'test_view',
    '#display_id' => 'block',
    '#arguments' => [$tid],
    '#embed' => TRUE,
  ],
```

Comment: I didn't know that it's so easy. Thank you.

Comment: This solution is extremely smart and elegant

Answer (score 13):

```
/**
 * Return the rendered view with contextual filter.
 * @param string $viewId - The view machine name.
 * @param string $displayId - The display machine name.
 * @param array $arguments - The arguments to pass.
 * 
 * @return object $result
 */
function getView($viewId, $displayId, array $arguments)
{
    $result = false;
    $view = Views::getView($viewId);

    if (is_object($view)) {
        $view->setDisplay($displayId);
        $view->setArguments($arguments);
        $view->execute();

        // Render the view
        $result = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($view->render());
    }

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Get json output.
 * @return array $data
 */
function jsonData() {
    $data = [];
    $viewId = 'rest_comments';
    $displayId = 'rest_export_1';
    $arguments = [$nid];

    // Get the view
    $result = getView($viewId, $displayId, $arguments);

    if(is_object($result)) {
        $json = $result->jsonSerialize();
        $data = json_decode($json);
    }

    return $data;
}


/**
 * Get the view object.
 * @return object $view
 */
function view() {
    $viewId = 'rest_comments';
    $displayId = 'rest_export_1';
    $arguments = [$nid];

    // Get the view
    $view = getView($viewId, $displayId, $arguments);

    return $view;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To get the actual JSON output of the REST Export display you can do something like this:

```
$view = Views::getView('view_id');
$render_array = $view->buildRenderable('display_name', $args);
$rendered = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($render_array);
$json_string = $rendered->jsonSerialize();
$json_object = json_decode($rendered);
```

Comment: Working like charm, thanks imclean.

Comment: works perfectly, how to set the user requesting the view? e.g. the view requires a permission to show revisions.

Comment: Just noticed that you're version doesn't work with some revisions, Santo Boldižar's does

Comment: I was getting crazy trying to call a REST view from my module making the HTTP call, where I had difficulty passing the correct authentication, when it came to my mind that there had to be a way to call directly the view and I found this thread. (Comment added mainly to help search engines :) )

Answer (score 2):

This works almost everywhere I use it:

```
use Drupal\views\Views; // above

$activeContestId = 100; 
$view = Views::getView('mymodule_contestants');
$view->setDisplay('block_1');
// contextual relationship filter
$view->setArguments([$activeContestId]);
$view->execute();
$rendered = $view->render();
$output = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($rendered);
```

Source: [Render a view with contextual filters programmatically in Drupal 9](https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/render-view-contextual-filters-programmatically-drupal-9)