# How to exclude an user previously referenced in a field (User reference) from a Views block listing users?

Tags: 7, views

Using Drupal 7.69

I have built a views block to list all users from a team, based on a taxonomy field as contextual filter (the team content type and users share the same taxonomy field).

This block is displayed on the team page.

One user is the leader of the team and he is referenced in an User reference field within the team content type.

This leader is listed in the block.

Now I need to exclude the leader from the block, since he is displayed in another block of the team page.

How to build the Views block so this user referenced does not appear on the users list when viewing the team page?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Might be worth specifying what you mean by "Group" is that the groups module? organic groups module? Or something else? As it sounds like your questions revolves all around your grouping functionality.

Comment: My bad for the confusion, I am not using Organic Groups, let's say this is a content type called Team. Edited.

Comment: No problem, I think you might struggle to do this purely with views. I think you'd either need to look at altering the views query or results programmatically. Or alternatively create a custom block that gets the value from your leader field and then loads your view programatically (something like https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205722/how-do-i-programmatically-render-a-view-with-contextual-filters) and then you could add another contextual filter to your view for the uid and make it show all rows that dont match the value passed in the contextual filter.