# How do I pass a context filter to a block loaded by ajax?

Tags: forms, ajax

There is a block created in views that displays the values of the taxonomy term fields.
This block should be loaded when selecting a term from the select field in a custom form. Accordingly, the block needs to somehow pass the tid of the term selected in the form.
The Select field in the form is formed as follows:

```
$form['rq_program'] = array(
       '#type' => 'select',
       '#title' => t('Program'),
       '#options' => GetProgramNameArray(), 
       '#required'=> TRUE,
       '#ajax' => array(
          'callback' => 'GetTermInfo', 
          'wrapper' => 'form-ajax-content',
          'method' => 'html',
          'effect' => 'fade',        
        ),
    );
```

callback function:

```
function GetTermInfo($form, $form_state) {      
    $tid=$form_state['values']['rq_program']; //value from select
    
    $block = block_load('views', 'views_program_block');
    $content = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
    $output = drupal_render($content);
    return render($output);  
}
```

I can't understand how to pass $tid to the block, how to set up a context filter in this block to receive this $tid?

Answer (score 0):

If the block you generated uses a contextual filter, maybe this could be the answer: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/205731/98697

Comment: I found an incredibly simple solution:
views_embed_view('my_views', 'my_block', array($tid));